# spring mvc resource not found in form action login

Tags: spring-mvc

in login.jsp user input username and password, if username or password is not correct,then echo error message to ${error}. 
But when I type login button(http://localhost:8080/project_name/login.jsp),it navigates to  "http://localhost:8080/project_name/login",and shows resource [/project_name/login] not found. 

WebContent/login.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8"
    pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="login" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>username:&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="username" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>password:&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="password" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="login"></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <font color="red">${error}</font>
</body>
</html>
```

WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="4.0">
  <display-name>dbquery</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

src/com/wise/controller/LoginController.java

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {
    @Autowired
    LoginService service;
    @Autowired
    HttpServletRequest request; 

    @RequestMapping(value="/login")
    public ModelAndView doLogin() {
        String loginUrl = "/login.jsp";
        String successUrl = "/WEB-INF/jsp/query.jsp";
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        return service.doLogin(loginUrl, successUrl, username, password);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="4.0">
  <display-name>dbquery</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dbquery</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dbquery</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

and add new WebContent/WEB-INF/dbquery-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        classpath:/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        classpath:/org/springframework/context/config/spring-context.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan
        base-package="com.wise.controller" />
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />
</beans>
```